# Java: Check if two double values match on specific no of decimal places

Tags: java, double

Comparing those two values shall result in a "true":

```
53.9173333333333  53.9173
```

Comment: Should 53.91739999999 compare equal to 53.9173? Or to 53.9174?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want `a = 1.00001` and `b = 0.99999` be identified as equal:

```
return Math.abs(a - b) < 1e-4;
```

Otherwise, if you want `a = 1.00010` and `b = 1.00019` be identified as equal, and both `a` and `b` are positive and not huge:

```
return Math.floor(a * 10000) == Math.floor(b * 10000);
// compare by == is fine here because both sides are integral values.
// double can represent integral values below 2**53 exactly.
```

Otherwise, use the `truncate` method as shown in [Are there any functions for truncating a double in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976809/are-there-any-functions-for-truncating-a-double-in-java):

```
BigDecimal aa = new BigDecimal(a);
BigDecimal bb = new BigDecimal(b);
aa = aa.setScale(4, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
bb = bb.setScale(4, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
return aa.equals(bb);
```

Comment: Love these kind of solutions, simple and brilliant!

Comment: -1.  @Michael is right.  This solution is flawed.  I'd like your explanation as to why ` System.out.println(12512310271255125d == 12512310271255124d);` prints `true` if double can represent integral values exactly.  It's an obviously incorrect statement given the magnitudes doubles can work with.  Then there's the fact that you shouldn't be using `==` on reference types like `BigDecimal`, but that's an easy fix.

Comment: Cool downvote removed.  They're good solutions for most cases.

Comment: +1 for the `BigDecimal`, this really does what is asked, making is very maintainable. This is what should be the preferred solution until performance has shown to need improvement.

Comment: (-3.17156, -3.1715) returns false

Answer (score 17):

here is the simple example if you still need this :)

```
public static boolean areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(double a, double b) {

    a = a * 1000;

    b = b * 1000;

    int a1 = (int) a;

    int b1 = (int) b;

    if (a1 == b1) {
        System.out.println("it works");
        return true;
    }

    else
        System.out.println("it doesn't work");
    return false;
```

Answer (score 6):

Naively:

```
if(Math.abs(a-b) < 0.0001)
```

However, that's not going to work correctly for all values. It's actually impossible to get it to work as long as you're using `double`, because `double` is implemented as binary fractons and does not even *have* decimal places.

You'll have to convert your values to `String` or `BigDecimal` to make meaningful tests about their decimal places.

You may want to read [the Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/binary/) to improve your understanding of how floating point values work.

Comment: Doesnt that really depend on how you translate that line…? If you want to check if those values are equal up to a certain digit, you're right with the `String` solution, but most of the times where such a comparation will occur, you just want to know it the results are "close enough", and in those scenarios, the line is pretty right.

Answer (score 3):

Apache commons has this:
org.apache.commons.math3.util.Precision equals(double x, double y, double eps)

epsilon would be the distance you would allow.  Looks like yours would be 1e-5?

The source-code of this method looks like it uses Math.abs as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(double a, double b){
    if(a < 0 && b < 0) {
        double c = Math.ceil(a * 1000) / 1000;
        double d = Math.ceil(b * 1000) / 1000;
        return c == d;
    }
    if(a > 0 && b > 0){
        double c = Math.floor(a * 1000) / 1000;
        double d = Math.floor(b * 1000) / 1000;
        return c == d;
    }
    return a == b;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please explain your solution.

Comment: The method Math.floor returns the largest Double data type that is less than or equal to the argument and is equal to mathematical integer.

The method Math.ceil returns the smallest Double data type that is greater than or equal to the argument and is equal to mathematical integer.

That's why I used Math.ceil for negative numbers and Math.floor for positive numbers. if non of the conditions is true than numbers are equal.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(double a, double b) {

if(a > 0 && b >0){
    return ((int)Math.floor(a * 1000) == (int)Math.floor(b * 1000));
}
else if (a < 0 && b <0) {
    return ((int)Math.ceil(a * 1000) == (int)Math.ceil(b * 1000));
}

return a==b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I did it this way:

```
double lon = 23.567889;
BigDecimal bdLon = new BigDecimal(lon);
bdLon = bdLon.setScale(4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

System.out.println(bdLon.doubleValue());
```

Comment: You don't have to make a new answer, just accept the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean areEqualBySixDecimalPlaces(double a, double b) {
        int num1 = (int) (a * 1e6);
        int num2 = (int) (b * 1e6);
        return num1 == num2;
    }
```

Casting up to desired digits shall be the simplest solution if you know the values

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead u can have a laugh over this one!!

```
public static boolean areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(double v, double v1) {


    if((int)v == (int)v1){

        String s = ""+v;
        String s1 = ""+v1;

        s = s.substring(s.indexOf(".")+1,s.indexOf(".")+4);
        s1 = s1.substring(s1.indexOf(".")+1,s1.indexOf(".")+4);

        return s.equals(s1);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: this way we don't have to deal with the auto rounding of decimals by java :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   public class DecimalComparator 
   {
       public static boolean areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(double a, double b) 
       {
           double threshold = 0.001;  // This represents 1e-3 or 0.001
           double diff = Math.abs(a - b);
           return diff <threshold;
       } 
   }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The solution to compare two double-digits up to three decimal places and return true or false might be:

```java
public static boolean areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(double myFirstNumber , double mySecondNumber){
    if (Math.abs(myFirstNumber - mySecondNumber) < 0.0009 ){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only returning `false`. You should replace the whole method body to `return Math.abs(myFirstNumber - mySecondNumber) < 0.0009;`.

Answer (score -1):

**try this one**

public static boolean isItEqual(double num1, double num2){ 
long firstDigit = (long)(num1 * 1000);
long secondDigit = (long)(num2 * 1000);
return firstDigit == secondDigit;
}

Comment: That doesn't work.

Comment: This question is 13.5 years old and there are already several highly-voted answers. Are you sure that this answer is different from all of them? Why should we use this instead of what's already here?