# Explanation why this works to find two the number equal to three decimal places

Tags: java

Trying to understand why this code works to find two numbers equal to three decimals places.

The casting (int) is catching me off guard(can't wrap my head around it).....

```java
public static boolean areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(double firstValue, double secondValue) {
    int moveThreeDecimalPlacesToRight = (int) Math.pow(10, 3);
    return (int) (firstValue * moveThreeDecimalPlacesToRight) == (int) (secondValue * moveThreeDecimalPlacesToRight);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first please take a look to [Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.1) and understand how does cast expressions works.

According to that chapter here is a short summary:

- `intValue` * `doubleValue` will be a `double`
- you can cast (in this case downcast) the type so `(int)(doubleValue * intValue)` will be casted to `int`
- If you cast a `double` to `int` explicitly you will lose decimals.

Now let's analyze that code step-by-step.

```java
//Just for the example let fisrtValue is 123.456789 and secondValue is 123.456999
double firstValue = 123.456789
double secondValue = 123.456999
```

```
(firstValue * moveThreeDecimalPlacesToRight)
// 123.456789 * 1000 will be a double 123456.789
```

```
(secondValue * moveThreeDecimalPlacesToRight)
// 123.456999 * 1000 will be a double 123456.999
```

```
return 123456.789 == 123456.999 will always return false
```

```
(int) (firstValue * moveThreeDecimalPlacesToRight)
// 123.456789 * 1000 will be an int 123456
```

```
(int) (secondValue * moveThreeDecimalPlacesToRight)
// 123.456999 * 1000 will be an int 123456
```

Finally

```java
return (int) (firstValue * moveThreeDecimalPlacesToRight) == (int) (secondValue * moveThreeDecimalPlacesToRight);
// return 123456 == 123456 will return true
```

```java
public static boolean areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(double firstValue, double secondValue) {
    // Math.pow(...) retuns a double so it have to downcast to int
    int moveThreeDecimalPlacesToRight = (int) Math.pow(10, 3);
    /* 
     * We don't care about just the first three decimal places
     * If fisrtValue is 123.456789 then 
     * firstValue * moveThreeDecimalPlacesToRight will be 123456.789
     * and secondValue * moveThreeDecimalPlacesToRight will be 123456.999
     * so both of them must be downcasted to int 
     * because 123456.789 will never be equal to 123456.999
    */
    return (int) (firstValue * moveThreeDecimalPlacesToRight) == (int) (secondValue * moveThreeDecimalPlacesToRight);
}
```

### UPDATE

Following @Eritrean's advice I have to mention that is a very bad idea. 
According the [Conversion Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) more precisely the Narrowing Primitive Conversion section:

> A narrowing primitive conversion may lose information about the overall magnitude of a numeric value and may also lose precision and range.

So if you have a large double number wich downcasted to int then your method can return false positive value.

I've just found two (or more) better options to solve your problem:

- A very good explanation how to do it wihout 3rd party libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2944352/5043481
- Apache Commons has utility classes which help you: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/index.html?org/apache/commons/math3/util/Precision.html

Comment: A typo: It should be `* 1000` and not `* 100` . And it might be worth mentioning that the method is a bad idea to compare doubles as it will fail for large numbers where casting to int will overflow. `areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(123456789.123,123456789.777)` will return true where it should be false. Nevertheless good explained.

Comment: I totally agree with you, @Eritrean that is totally bad idea. Typo fixed.