# How can I truncate a double to only two decimal places in Java?

Tags: java, double, truncate, decimalformat

For example I have the variable 3.545555555, which I would want to truncate to just 3.54.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

If you want that for display purposes, use [`java.text.DecimalFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
 new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(dblVar);
```

If you need it for calculations, use [`java.lang.Math`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html):

```
 Math.floor(value * 100) / 100;
```

Comment: This will **not** display a truncated 3.545555555 to 3.54, but rounded to 3.55. DecimalFormat.setRoundingMode() needs to be set to RoundingMode.FLOOR;

Comment: this doesn't work for me Math.floor(9.62 * 100) / 100  gives 9.61

Comment: Using `floor` to truncate only works for positive values.

Comment: @ChristianGarcía Truncation is properly done with `RoundingMode.DOWN` as `RoudingMode.FLOOR` always rounds towards negative infinity.

Comment: Second approach won't work always, check: Math.floor(2.28 * 100)/100 = 2.27

Answer (score 47):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(fmt);
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
s = df.format(d);
```

Check available [`RoundingMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) and [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Comment: Does not address the Question, which asked for truncation rather than rounding.

Comment: @BasilBourque RoundingMode.DOWN is truncation. Compare with other answers that incorrectly recommend floor functions (floor only truncates positive numbers), this works correctly for both positive and negative values.

Comment: @Dev I stand corrected. I see now that `DOWN` does indeed have the effect of truncation for both positive and negative numbers. As seen in examples table in [the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html).

Answer (score 31):

None of the other answers worked for both positive and negative values ( I mean for the calculation and just to do "truncate" without Rounding). and without converting to string.

From the [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java) link

```
private static BigDecimal truncateDecimal(double x,int numberofDecimals)
{
    if ( x > 0) {
        return new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(x)).setScale(numberofDecimals, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
    } else {
        return new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(x)).setScale(numberofDecimals, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING);
    }
}
```

This method worked fine for me .

```
System.out.println(truncateDecimal(0, 2));
    System.out.println(truncateDecimal(9.62, 2));
    System.out.println(truncateDecimal(9.621, 2));
    System.out.println(truncateDecimal(9.629, 2));
    System.out.println(truncateDecimal(9.625, 2));
    System.out.println(truncateDecimal(9.999, 2));
    System.out.println(truncateDecimal(-9.999, 2));
    System.out.println(truncateDecimal(-9.0, 2));
```

Results :

```
0.00
9.62
9.62
9.62
9.62
9.99
-9.99
-9.00
```

Comment: this is the answer mor scalable for more test case

Comment: return new BigDecimal(x).setScale(numberofDecimals, RoundingMode.DOWN).doubleValue();

Comment: seems round down is like what you meant: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html

Comment: @ShimonDoodkin `String.valueOf(x)` is required, otherwise it would work incorrectly on e.g. 2.28, 9.62 or 9411.3

Answer (score 9):

Note first that a `double` is a binary fraction and does not really *have* decimal places.

If you need decimal places, use a `BigDecimal`, which has a `setScale()` method for truncation, or use `DecimalFormat` to get a `String`.

Answer (score 9):

Formating as a string and converting back to double i think will give you the result you want.

The double value will not be round(), floor() or ceil().

A quick fix for it could be:

```
 String sValue = (String) String.format("%.2f", oldValue);
 Double newValue = Double.parseDouble(sValue);
```

You can use the sValue for display purposes or the newValue for calculation.

Comment: It does round for me to the nearest value. For eg: 0.018 is converted to 0.02 when I did this.

Answer (score 7):

If, for whatever reason, you don't want to use a `BigDecimal` you can cast your `double` to an `int` to truncate it.

If you want to truncate to the *Ones* place:

- simply cast to `int`

To the *Tenths* place:

- multiply by ten
- cast to `int`
- cast back to `double`
- and divide by ten.

*Hundreths* place

- multiply and divide by 100 etc.

Example:

```
static double truncateTo( double unroundedNumber, int decimalPlaces ){
    int truncatedNumberInt = (int)( unroundedNumber * Math.pow( 10, decimalPlaces ) );
    double truncatedNumber = (double)( truncatedNumberInt / Math.pow( 10, decimalPlaces ) );
    return truncatedNumber;
}
```

In this example, `decimalPlaces` would be the number of places PAST the ones place you wish to go, so 1 would round to the *tenths* place, 2 to the *hundredths*, and so on (0 rounds to the *ones* place, and negative one to the tens, etc.)

Comment: This is a *terrible* general solution. Both the multiply and the cast will end up throwing away data and resulting in what are effectively random numbers if `unroundedNumber` is big enough. It may work for the example in the question, but a general solution should work for any `double`.

Comment: Does not work correctly on e.g. 2.28, 9.62 or 9411.3

Answer (score 6):

You can use NumberFormat Class object to accomplish the task.

```
// Creating number format object to set 2 places after decimal point
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);            
nf.setGroupingUsed(false);

System.out.println(nf.format(precision));// Assuming precision is a double type variable
```

Comment: I would also add `nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2)`;

Answer (score 5):

3.545555555 to get 3.54.
Try Following for this:

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);

    double result = new Double(df.format(3.545555555);
```

This will give= 3.54!

Comment: But i will get 3.5 if i set that value is 3.50123

Comment: @Cyrus 3.5 is a correct result though for 3.50123. trunc(2) sort of function should truncate it to 3.50.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `Math.floor(value * 100) / 100`? Beware that the values like `3.54` may be not exactly represented with a `double`.

Comment: Unforunately, there are counter-examples where this doesn't work:

    double value = 9411.3;
    System.out.println(Math.floor(value * 100) / 100);
    // 9411.29

Comment: Does not work correctly on e.g. 2.28, 9.62 or 9411.3

Comment: @DKroot: Depends on what you'd call "correctly". When you say `double value = 2.28;`, your `value` will be actually `2.279999999999999804600747665972448885440826416015625`, so after truncating you'd get a honest `2.27`. From my point of view, the problem is not with truncating, the problem is with assignment.

Comment: I know about binary precision loss. That's why trunc() is a dangerous operation. 
However, by "correctly", I mean "as expected from a user/math perspective": E.g. `assert(2.28.trunc(2)) == 2.28` where `trunc(precision)` is a truncation method. For example, see this blog post (not mine): https://blog.mrhaki.com/2010/01/groovy-goodness-round-and-truncate.html

Comment: @DKroot: It's the line "double d = 2.28;" which behaves wrong from the naïve user's perspective. You must know that that there is no such double number as 2.28, right? My code sees 2.279999... as input, and it has no clue (and must not have!) that the argument comes from the unsound assumption that it must have actually been 2.28 decimal. The code gets the number which is strictly less than 2.28, and produces the correct result.

Comment: @DKroot: If someone wants the number which strictly corresponds to its decimal representation, the appropriate type is e. g. [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), not the binary-based `double`. But that's not the topic of the discussed question.

Comment: @DKroot: About Groovy example from the blog post you mentioned: https://groovyide.com/cpi/share/v1/VVA7b8MgEP4rlClRLAZPlaNuHbJk7cRC4OIi4TvEo1Vk8d97dp0mZeG-x30cN0uPsRY5zPJC7iYHKTv5CcZBygtJwZ1WxMoJQqAX2ToZE0VIxcPiaUxkm3xcUyw5YK-fIqUiLE0qm6hGU-Db3JSPylICZWsuNDn4UrX4oM6QsxnhqFGjg6vYsOB3LJfvppjdnZt-773GWaPgszQ4qpcAHyZUEG-iV_2rOz7UkipansCx9uRUK7_r95s1Jo8loNCSkh89mjBwLQ7_0g9MdY_EzfGHt6gEpSa8z8pk08iLvbKreEJe0NPXZGs_

Answer (score 2):

Here is the method I use:

```
double a=3.545555555; // just assigning your decimal to a variable
a=a*100;              // this sets a to 354.555555
a=Math.floor(a);      // this sets a to 354
a=a/100;              // this sets a to 3.54 and thus removing all your 5's
```

This can also be done:

```
a=Math.floor(a*100) / 100;
```

Comment: Does not work correctly on e.g. 2.28, 9.62 or 9411.3

Answer (score 2):

I used Math.floor() method and basic moving of decimal places by (100 = 2).

```
//3.545555555 to 3.54 by floor method
double x = 3.545555555;
double y = Math.floor(x * 100); //354
double z = y / 100; //3.54
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick check is to use the Math.floor method.  I created a method to check a double for two or less decimal places below:

```
public boolean checkTwoDecimalPlaces(double valueToCheck) {

    // Get two decimal value of input valueToCheck 
    double twoDecimalValue = Math.floor(valueToCheck * 100) / 100;

    // Return true if the twoDecimalValue is the same as valueToCheck else return false
    return twoDecimalValue == valueToCheck;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe following :

```
double roundTwoDecimals(double d) { 
      DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); 
      return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
}
```

Comment: See the other answers. You can't do it reliably if the answer is to be represented in floating point.

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly modified version of [Mani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2182351/mani)'s.

```
private static BigDecimal truncateDecimal(final double x, final int numberofDecimals) {
    return new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(x)).setScale(numberofDecimals, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(truncateDecimal(0, 2));
    System.out.println(truncateDecimal(9.62, 2));
    System.out.println(truncateDecimal(9.621, 2));
    System.out.println(truncateDecimal(9.629, 2));
    System.out.println(truncateDecimal(9.625, 2));
    System.out.println(truncateDecimal(9.999, 2));
    System.out.println(truncateDecimal(3.545555555, 2));

    System.out.println(truncateDecimal(9.0, 2));
    System.out.println(truncateDecimal(-9.62, 2));
    System.out.println(truncateDecimal(-9.621, 2));
    System.out.println(truncateDecimal(-9.629, 2));
    System.out.println(truncateDecimal(-9.625, 2));
    System.out.println(truncateDecimal(-9.999, 2));
    System.out.println(truncateDecimal(-9.0, 2));
    System.out.println(truncateDecimal(-3.545555555, 2));

}
```

Output:

```
0.00
9.62
9.62
9.62
9.62
9.99
9.00
3.54
-9.62
-9.62
-9.62
-9.62
-9.99
-9.00
-3.54
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      double value = 3.4555;
      String value1 =  String.format("% .3f", value) ;
      String value2 = value1.substring(0, value1.length() - 1);
      System.out.println(value2);         
      double doublevalue= Double.valueOf(value2);
      System.out.println(doublevalue);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and congratulations on your first answer. While the code you posted may address the question asked by the original poster, you should add a few sentences to explain how your solution is better or more suited than the (many) other answers for some specific situations.

Answer (score 0):

double firstValue = -3.1756d;

double value1 = (((int)(Math.pow(10,3)*firstValue))/Math.pow(10,3));

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In this solution, this will **TRUNCATE** a double to only two decimal places. This solution will **not ROUND OFF** the double value.

```
double myDoubleNumber = 3.545555555;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
double myDoubleNumberTruncated = Double.parseDouble(df.format(myDoubleNumber));
System.out.println(myDoubleNumberTruncated);
```

*This will output **3.54***

**DecimalFormat("#.##")** - Here, I entered two hash symbols(##) after the decimal point. Hence, this will truncate the number up to two decimal places.

**This will work for both Positive & Negative values.**

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:

```
double input = 104.8695412  //For example

long roundedInt = Math.round(input * 100);
double result = (double) roundedInt/100;

//result == 104.87
```

I personally like this version because it actually performs the rounding numerically, rather than by converting it to a String (or similar) and then formatting it.

Comment: The original question is about truncating, not rounding. Also, converting a double to a long won't work well at all if the double is large enough.