# Convert milliseconds to TDateTime in Java

Tags: java, android, delphi

I'm in an Android project that requires saving a file with `TDateTime` type (Delphi). I have my date in milliseconds, but I don't know how to convert milliseconds to `TDateTime`.

I have something like this:

```
Date dateInMillis = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
double dateInDouble = ???;
```

I'll be glad for any tips that can help me to resolve this.

Comment: use java Datetime function to convert milliseconds to Datetime

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Delphi's `TDateTime` measures time in days. Java follows the Unix standard and measures in milliseconds. To convert between the two you need to scale by the number of milliseconds in a day, `86400000`.

The other difference is that the two systems use a different epoch. The Unix epoch, as used by Java, is 00:00, 1 Jan 1970. The Delphi epoch is 00:00, 30 December 1899. The Unix epoch, represented as a Delphi `TDateTime` is `25569`.

So, to convert from milliseconds from the Unix epoch, to days from the Delphi epoch you perform the following calculation:

```
double delphiDateTime = unixMillis/86400000.0 + 25569.0;
```

Comment: That´s what I did a few minutes ago! I need wait 8 hours to Answer my own question but this is exactly what I did!
Thanks David

Answer (score 1):

More recently post Java 8 with the new date time classes, the following should work:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0);//Delphi date EPOCH time start
double fraction = val % 1;
long intPart = (long) (val - fraction);
localDateTime = localDateTime.plus(intPart, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
localDateTime = localDateTime.plus((long) (24*60*60*1000 * fraction), ChronoUnit.MILLIS); //fraction is a fraction of the time of day
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use modern *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted `Date` class.

```java
Duration duration =
        Duration.between(
                LocalDate.of( 1899 , Month.DECEMBER , 30 ).atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toInstant() ,  // Epoch reference moment used by Delphi.
                Instant.now()  // Current moment as seen in UTC.
        );
double temp =
        // Get a whole number of days (integer ) + a decimal fraction of partial day = a `double` number = the `TDateTime` type in Delphi.
        duration.toDays() +
                (
                        ( double ) duration.minusDays( duration.toDays() ).toMillis()     // Milliseconds in our partial day.
                                /
                                ( double ) Duration.ofDays( 1 ).toMillis()                // Milliseconds in a full day, a generic 24-hour day.
                );
double r = Math.floor( temp * 1000 ) / 1000;  // Truncate to third decimal place to represent a resolution of milliseconds, the limit of `TDateTime` type in Delphi.
```

## *java.time*

Use only the modern *java.time* classes in Java, never the legacy classes such as `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`.

Capture the current moment as seen in UTC.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
```

Because of some [twisted history](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=TDateTime), as its [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) for its `TDateTime` class Delphi uses the first moment of 1899-12-30 presumably in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). For the date portion, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
LocalDate delphiEpochDate = LocalDate.of( 1899 , Month.DECEMBER , 30 ); // No, not the 31st, the 30th.
```

> epochDate.toString(): 1899-12-30

As a habit, let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day, as it is not always 00:00 on all dates in all zones.

```
Instant delphiEpochMoment = delphiEpochDate.atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toInstant();
```

> odt.toString(): 1899-12-30T00:00Z

Delphi uses a terrible method of tracking time as inherited from spreadsheets: Using a `double` floating-point fractional number.

The integer portion represents full days, generic 24-hour long days that ignore the anomalies of political time. For such elapsed time, we use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html).

```
Duration d = Duration.between( delphiEpochMoment , now ) ;
long days = d.toDays() ;  // Generic 24-hour long days.
```

Next, get the fractional part that represents a portion of a 24-hour day. First we subtract the amount of the full days, to leave us with a partial day.

```
Duration partialDay = d.minusDays( days ) ;
```

Then divide the partial amount by the length of a full day. We will use a resolution of milliseconds rather than the nanoseconds capability of `Duration`, as it seems Delphi is limited to milliseconds.

```
double millisOfPartialDay = partialDay.toMillis() ;
double millisOfFullDay = Duration.ofDays( 1 ).toMillis() ;
double tempResult = ( millisOfPartialDay / millisOfFullDay ) ;
```

We should truncate results to milliseconds. For truncating a `double`, see [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18355429/642706). And we should add our whole number of days.

```
double tempResult = days + ( millisOfPartialDay / millisOfFullDay ) ;
double result = Math.floor( tempResult * 1000 ) / 1000 ;
```

Putting that all together.

```java
Instant now = Instant.now();

LocalDate delphiEpochDate = LocalDate.of( 1899 , Month.DECEMBER , 30 ); // No, not the 31st, the 30th.
Instant delphiEpochMoment = delphiEpochDate.atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toInstant();

Duration d = Duration.between( delphiEpochMoment , now );
long days = d.toDays();  // Generic 24-hour long days.

Duration partialDay = d.minusDays( days );

double millisOfPartialDay = partialDay.toMillis();
double millisOfFullDay = Duration.ofDays( 1 ).toMillis();

double tempResult = days + ( millisOfPartialDay / millisOfFullDay );
double result = Math.floor( tempResult * 1000 ) / 1000;  // Truncate to third decimal place to represent a resolution of milliseconds.

System.out.println( "delphiEpochMoment = " + delphiEpochMoment );
System.out.println( "d = " + d );
System.out.println( "tempResult = " + tempResult );
System.out.println( "result = " + result );
```

> delphiEpochMoment = 1899-12-30T00:00:00Z

> d = PT1056815H56M10.613011S

> tempResult = 44033.99734505787

> result = 44033.997

**Caveat:** I have not tested this code. And I do not use Delphi. So buyer beware: this code is worth every penny you paid for it.

### Avoid `LocalDateTime`

Beware: Do *not* use `LocalDateTime` to represent a moment. This class represents a date with time-of-day, but lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. For example, take the value of Noon on January 23rd of 2021. Would that be noon in Tokyo Japan? Or noon in Toulouse France? Or noon in Toledo Ohio US? Those would be three very different moments, several hours apart. We do not know which is intended if the time zone is lacking.

You could get away with `LocalDateTime` in this specific problem of Delphi time-tracking because Delphi (presumably) uses UTC, and UTC uses generic 24-hour-long days as does `LocalDateTime`. But using `LocalDateTime` is conceptually not fit for this problem, as we need moments for here.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]