# Formatting floating point values in Java

Tags: java

I tried to use this:

```
String t="4.99999999";
t = String.format("%.2f",Float.valueOf(t));
```

I wanted it to print `4.99`, but it wrote `5.00`. Do you know why?

Comment: Because 5.00 is closer to 4.99999999 than is 4.99.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues, here. One is that floats can't differentiate between `4.99999999` and `5.0`, i.e. `Float.valueOf()` parses it as `5.0`. Doubles *do* have enough precision. The other issue is that 5.0 is the correct behavior for `%2f`. You're asking for two decimal points, and 4.99999999  clearly rounds up to 5.00. Since the `String.format()` behavior isn't what you want, what do you want, i.e. *why* is 4.99 the correct behavior for your use case?

Edit: if you're trying to *truncate* two two decimal points, look here: [How can I truncate a double to only two decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747469/how-can-i-truncate-a-double-to-only-two-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

In general, you **must not** use floats (or doubles), when thinking of decimal numbers.

Simple example:

```
System.out.println(0.33333333333333333 + 0.1);
```

will print:

```
0.43333333333333335
```

Java will internally store floats and doubles as "binary values". And converting decimal factions into binary fractions will cause a lot of surprising things.

If you want to handle decimal numbers you **have to** use `BigDecimal` or a similar class.

An example of how to use this:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Snippet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // define the value as a decimal number
        BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("4.99999999");

        // round the decimal number to 2 digits after the decimal separator
        // using the rounding mode, that just chops off any other decimal places
        value.setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN);

        // define a format, that numbers should be displayed like
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

        // use the format to transform the value into a string
        String stringRepresentation = format.format(value);

        // print string
        System.out.println(stringRepresentation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to show `4.99` why don't you  extract the substring

```
String t="4.99999999";
int i =  t.indexOf('.');
if(i != -1){
    t = t.substring(0, Math.min(i + 3, t.length()));
}
```

If you want it to to always have two decimal places then you use `BigDecimal`. With `BigDecimal` you can set scale to 2 decimal places and round down so numbers like `4` prints out `4.00`

```
 String t="4";
 BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(t).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
 System.out.println(bd); //prints out 4.00
```

Comment: @user3160197 it doesn't matter, this will always work. Searching for the decimal point is linear.

Comment: @user3160197 I made a mistake, `min` instead of `max`

Comment: thanks Its good One problem is the max I think is min

Comment: That approach would be a lot cleaner with a regular expression, e.g. ```\d+\.\d{2}```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
System.out.println(((int)(Float.valueOf(t) * 100))/100.0);
```

Comment: but I want it to work also if the number is 2342323.23423423421897

Comment: Then use log10 to find the number k of leading digits and pow(10,k+2) instead of 100 in the example.