# Please specify the reason for the given output in following java code

Tags: java

Why does the following Java code print the output `2342245.75000000` instead of `2342245.80000000`?

```
float n=2342245.8f;
System.out.printf("%.8f\n",n);
```

Output:

```
2342245.75000000
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367229/formatting-floating-point-values-in-java

Comment: and maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-double-in-java

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that `2342245.8f == 2342245.75f`. They are the same floating-point number; just two different decimal representations. The precision of floats at that magnitude is such that only two bits are used for the fractional part; so the next float below it is `2342245.5f`, and the next one above is `2342246.0f`. There are no other floats in between those two numbers.

The difference in what you see on the screen is purely string formatting: `2342245.8` is the *shortest* string which will be rounded to that floating point number, so that's what `String.valueOf` returns, and hence that's what you'll see if you just do `System.out.println`. But `2342245.75` is a more accurate decimal representation, which is used by the `printf` method because you told that method to use more decimal places.