# How can I clip the first two digits of a number box item?

Tags: android, numbers, number-formatting

I have a program and a layout for coordinate input.

I'm entering latitude and longitude values. When the cordinates are close to each other (for example lat1:21.424521 and lat2:21.424534 ), and it gets really annoying to input all coordinates.

Does anyone know  how can I get first two digits of the first values so i dont have write them multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double lat1 = 21.424521;
lat1 = new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(lat1));
```

This will, for example, trimm it down to two decimals. If you want only 2 digits, you would do it like this:

```
lat1 = new DecimalFormat("##").format(lat1));
```

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

```
new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(dblVar);
```

That is what you need, if I understand your question correctly.

**Example:**

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
s = df.format(lat);  // or df.format(lng);
```

**Source:**

[How can I truncate a double to only two decimal places in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747469/how-can-i-truncate-a-double-to-only-two-decimal-places-in-java)