# How to generate a list of random real numbers

Tags: java

How do I generate a list of random real numbers between a specific range, ex. -50 to 50? The function I wrote returns a list of only doubles. What I want it to return is something like this: 35, -3, 1.6, 4.5, -22.8, 10, -12, 5.2, 3.6, -8. Here's what I've tried so far...any help is appreciated!

```
public static double [] randomArray(int A)
{
    double [] randomArr = new double[A];
    Random r = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < A; i++)
        {
            randomArr[i] = (r.nextDouble() *(100)) - 50;
        }
    return randomArr;
}
```

Comment: I am afraid that I don’t understand the difference between what you asked for and what you got? Did you want numbers with only 1 decimal? Did you want real real numbers rather than numbers of type `double`?

Comment: *real numbers* is a bad term to use here due to its mathematical definition. It seems that you want a mixture of `int` and `double` where the `double` values are only precise to the first decimal place. Is that correct?

Comment: @JacobG sorry, my bad. But yes, that's what I meant to say.

Comment: Thanks, @user11082882, for clarifying. Please always do so *in the question itself*. Use the edit link. Your chances of good answers are considerably greater when readers only need to read the question and not the comments.

Answer (score 2):

## Randomly switch between randomly generating a whole or fractional number

You seem to be asking for a random mix of whole numbers (integers, `int` or `Integer`) and fractional numbers (`float` or `double`, `Float` or `Double`). I assume you understand that a random `Float`/`Double` *could* turn out to be a whole number with a fraction of zero, but want to dramatically increase the presence of whole numbers.

There may be more clever ways, but I would use a random number to choose between generating the next number as an integer or as a fractional.

As a random number generator, I suggest [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt(int)) as it is [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) by design.

If you want to constrain the range of possible values, specify the optional [origin and bound](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt(int,int)). I cannot imagine why, but it appears that there is no option to specify origin/bound when generating floats, so you must use doubles.

If you want to truncate the fraction to a specific number of digits, see [*How can I truncate a double to only two decimal places in Java?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7747469/642706).

Example code.

```
int initialCapacity = 10;
List < Number > numbers = new ArrayList <>( initialCapacity );

for ( int i = 1 ; i <= initialCapacity ; i++ )
{
    int which = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 2 ); // Produce either 0 or 1. The bound is exclusive, so we specify `2`.
    switch ( which )
    {
        case 0:
            numbers.add( ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( - 50 , 50 ) );
            break;
        case 1:
            numbers.add( ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble( - 50 , 50 ) );
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException( "The `which` switch should be only zero or one. Message # 108d8e3f-bce7-4f0f-8dff-652940a17ba1." );
    }
}
```

When run:

> numbers.toString(): [28.344775355282835, -36.00411659190424, 4.151429648004303, -26.898964417043725, 31, 4, 17.172537217625035, 4, 29.957510122739222, -46]

My code assumes you want approximately half and half whole and fractional numbers. If you want a different ratio, play with the range of `which` and change the `switch` to a cascading `if` statement that tests for ranges of numbers. For example, if you want 20% whole numbers, generate 1-10 and result of 1 & 2 produce an `Integer` while 3-10 produce a `Float`. Again, there may be more clever approaches mathematically, but this approach gets the job done.

## `BigDecimal`

The `float`/`double` & `Float`/`Double` types use [floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) technology. Floating-point trades away accuracy for speed of execution. So some numbers cannot be represented to exactly 2 decimal places, for example.

If you care about accuracy more than speed (such as when handling money), substitute `BigDecimal` where my code used `Double`.

## Auto-boxing

My code above generates a `double` primitive value, while the `List` stores objects. Java automatically wraps the primitive as a `Double` object before storing in the array. If you are unfamiliar with this trick, learn about [auto-boxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming)#Autoboxing). See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use DecimalFormat.

Snipplet:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.text.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Number Format Sample!");
    int n = 5;
    double [] randomArr = randomArray(n);
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.#");

      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
            System.out.println("randomArr item : "+format.format(randomArr[i]));
      }
  }
  public static double [] randomArray(int A)
  {
    double [] randomArr = new double[A];
    Random r = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < A; i++)
        {
            randomArr[i] =(r.nextDouble() *(100)) - 50;
        }
    return randomArr;
}
}
```

Output:

```
Number Format Sample!
randomArr item : -30.8
randomArr item : -36.9
randomArr item : 44.2
randomArr item : 13.6
randomArr item : -49.1
```

Ref:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: Another way of saying this is that there is no *good* way of storing a limited precision number.  Instead you store full floats or doubles and then round them when you display them for output.

Answer (score 0):

Generates values between -50.0..50.0 inclusive with one decimal point of precision (eg. `42.5`).  Note: Not all decimal values can be contained perfectly as a floating point value.

```
for (int i = 0; i < A; i++)
{
    double value = (r.nextInt(501) / 10.0) * (r.nextBoolean() ? 1 : -1);
    randomArr[i] = value;
}
```