# Double decimal formatting issue

Tags: java, decimal, decimalformat

I have a double number which is 8.775. I want to make it to where it'll print 8.77. I tried this line of code but Java keeps rounding it to 8.78. Is there any way around this?

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", 8.775);
```

Comment: Then you need not round but to truncate digits. Because 8.775 would be rou ded ru 8.78 according to usual rounding rules

Comment: Building on what @Ivan said I would just find the index of the decimal and then take the substring from 0, index + 2. Be careful and make sure that the string is also that long.

Comment: You want to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747469/how-can-i-truncate-a-double-to-only-two-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want control over the rounding used in converting a `double` to a `String` you need to use `DecimalFormat`.

You either want `FLOOR` ,which rounds towards negative infinity, or `DOWN`, which rounds towards zero, depending on the desired behavior with negative numbers (for positive numbers they produce the same results):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");

df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
System.out.println("FLOOR");
System.out.println(df.format(8.775));
System.out.println(df.format(-8.775));

System.out.println("DOWN");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
System.out.println(df.format(8.775));
System.out.println(df.format(-8.775));
```

Output:

```
FLOOR
8.77
-8.78

DOWN
8.77
-8.77
```

Answer (score 3):

For rounding double to the floor you would have to write your own function(or use DecimalFormat) or you can for example use Bigdecimal which already has this built-in.

```
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(8.775).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR));
```

Output:

```
8,77
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double val = 8.775;    

double output = new BigDecimal(val)
                .setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR)
                .doubleValue();

System.out.println(output);            // 8.77
System.out.printf("%.2f\n", output);   // 8.77
```