# Compare two double values in Java

Tags: java, double, comparison

This is a Java code that should test whether the first three digits after the decimal point are identical. And I need to write this program without a main method.

```java
public class areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces {
    public static boolean areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(double d_1, double d_2) {
        double value_1 = Math.round(1000*d_1);
        double value_2 = Math.round(1000*d_2);

        if (value_1 == value_2) {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }
}
```

**Input:**

```
(-3.1756, -3.175)
```

**Expected Output:**

```
true
```

**Output received:**

```
false
```

By using the `Math.round` it is rounding the value of `-3.1756` to `-3.176`. But I want to check if the three digits after the decimal point are similar.

How do I correct my code?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to _truncate_ both doubles to three decimal places?

Answer (score 1):

Going off this code the two values just won't be equal.
value_1 = -3176.0
value_2 = -3175.0

If you want to learn a little more about truncating doubles, take a look at this.
[How can I truncate a double to only two decimal places in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747469/how-can-i-truncate-a-double-to-only-two-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You could to use **ceil** instead of **round**

```java
double value_1 = Math.ceil(d_1 * 1000);
double value_2 = Math.ceil(d_2 * 1000);
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to Alex Rudenko's comment, I realized that the correct solution would be using `ceil` for negative numbers and `floor` for positive numbers

```java
double value_1 = d_1 < 0 ? Math.ceil(d_1 * 1000) : Math.floor(d_1 * 1000);
double value_2 = d_2 < 0 ? Math.ceil(d_2 * 1000) : Math.floor(d_2 * 1000);
```

Fabio

Comment: This is a quick and incorrect solution: `Math.ceil` would work for a narrow case of negative inputs, for positive inputs `Math.floor` would be needed, so the sign should be taken into account. And anyway this does not compare _3 digits in the fractional part_.

Comment: Thank you for your remark, @AlexRudenko. Now that you make me think about it, the correct solution would be using `Math.ceil` for negative numbers and `Math.floor` for positive numbers. I will edit my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The code to check if *the first three digits after the decimal point are identical* should just truncate the integer part and *keep only the digits in the fractional part* by subtracting initial integer part.

Also, it may be needed to use `Math.abs` or `Math.sign` to compare the values retrieved from positive and negative inputs:
`areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(3.1751, -3.1758) == true`.

And the last thing: in order to avoid integer overflow for large inputs when multiplying by 1000 it's better to use `long`.

So the example implementation may look like this:

```java
public static boolean areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(double d1, double d2) {
    long value1 = Math.abs((long) (d1 * 1000L) - (long) d1 * 1000L); 
    long value2 = Math.abs((long) (d2 * 1000L) - (long) d2 * 1000L);

    System.out.print(value1 + " == " + value2 + " ? ");
    return value1 == value2;
}
```

or using a lambda for `DoubleToLongFunction`:

```java
public static boolean areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(double d1, double d2) {
    DoubleToLongFunction f = (d) -> Math.abs((long) (d * 1000L) - (long) d * 1000L);

    return f.applyAsLong(d1) == f.applyAsLong(d2);
}
```

Tests:

```java
System.out.println(areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(-3.175, -3.1752));
System.out.println(areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(3.175, 3.1752));
System.out.println(areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(3.1751, -3.1758));
System.out.println(areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(5_123_456_789.123987, -90_123_456_789.123456));
```

Output:

```
175 == 175 ? true
175 == 175 ? true
175 == 175 ? true
123 == 123 ? true
```