# How to truncate double number with adding missing zeros at the end

Tags: java, truncation

Consider I have some double number, I want to truncate it(not round) and leave 4 digits after floating point(exactly 4, always 4, if there are not enough digits - add zeros). Examples:

```
2344.4234934 -----> 2344.4234
1.345584 -----> 1.3455
34.3434 -------> 34.3434
0.123 ------> 0.1230
1 ---------> 1.0000
```

I'm using java language, and I'm asking for some built-in functions. I have a solution already but it's too complicated, may be there is an elegant one.

Comment: Could you please show your existing solution so we do not suggest that?

Comment: i used DecimalFormat with floor rounding mode, then I added missing zeros in old-school way + "0"

Comment: What format string did you use with the `DecimalFormat`?  That should be all you need to use.  You shouldn't need to do anything else with the string once it's returned.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any functions for truncating a double in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976809/are-there-any-functions-for-truncating-a-double-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.0000");
fmt.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
String s = fmt.format(myDouble);
```